# Wrapping the function with variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a new js file and I want to wrap my function to make sure that I am safeguarding it to collide with any other functions in other js files.
The issue that I am confused about is that I am using this:

```
var myVariable = (function (p1, p2) {    });
```

because I want to be able to invoke that method later on sometime by calling the variable. The above works just fine. However you can see that `myVariable` is not encapsulated. When I try to do this:

```
(var myVariable = function (p1, p2) {    });
```

that does not work. My question is how do I encapsulate that function so I can use it later?

Comment: Are you trying to encapsulate a function so much that even _you_ can't use it? If not, I'd wrap it in some sort of ["namespace"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/881556/5601284), or look at [IIFEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) _(Immediately Invoked Function Expressions)_

Comment: You don't need to wrap the function in `()` - if you simply do `var myVariable = function( /* args */) { /* code */}` you'll be able to access `myVariable` (assuming it's global) but everything inside the function will be scoped to being inside it.

Comment: What does the full function this code belongs to look like?

Comment: You can't both wrap your code to make sure it doesn't interfere, and at the same time have it globally accessible. Best case is that you create a single variable that doesn't clash with anything, and just chain everything onto that as properties, and then wrap the code in an IIFE returning the single variable.

Comment: ok so the way I am doing is correct then.

Comment: Are you trying to write a global helper function with AngularJS ?

Comment: JS modules (CommonJS, AMD, ES6, whatever) are actually supposed to serve this purpose. In the case of non-modular environment exposing something for reuse means polluting global scope. If the variable is used within single file, IIFE may be used as a workaround.